# Looking for computers on local network listening on certain port in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, monitoring

I am currently working on a very simple Python script. The idea is that I have 5 computers running on my local network, and I want to monitor them.

I have a python program that logs down the CPU and Memory usage to a text file. However, I want each computer to send their text file to all the other computers that are listening rather than sending them to a centralized computer to eliminate a single point of failure.

Thus, In my python script I want to look for all computers on a local network listening on a certain port and send them the text file. This means each computer would have the log data of all the other computers.

I looked for some tutorials on Python socket programming, but I was unable to find anything that resembles what I am trying to do.

My current script to log down info from one computer is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw9jc9-SSy8dV2FIaHBhcHhxZzQ/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks in advance

Comment: you would need a way for each computer to know the ip address of each other computer, I'd suggest storing a record on a master computer but that would defeat the purpose of the question to remove a single point failure.

Comment: You could use a UDP broadcast.

Comment: Thanks. @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen What I might implement is a master computer, as it is much simpler to do; but have each computer download the data from the master computer every hour. That shouldn't be a problem as it is just text files. So then all the data would be backed up everywhere.

Comment: I like @KlausD.'s idea. If your log data fits in a single datagram, you could do it all within a UDP broadcast message ("Here's my log data: <blob>"). If not, you can use the broadcast to say: "I have a log to send" and let anyone interested connect back (via TCP) to the sender to obtain the contents. Then you have no requirement for a master and no need to have a list of the other system's addresses.